# Select multiple users group with the highest display priority

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to make it select the group with the highest display priority.
The problem is that it selects the group with the lowest ID and I'm not sure how to select the group with the highest display priority.

The SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT xf_user_group_relation.user_id , 
       xf_user_field_value.field_value,
       xf_user_group_relation.user_group_id, 
       MAX( xf_user_group.display_style_priority ) AS display_style_priority 
FROM xf_user_group_relation
     INNER JOIN xf_user_group ON xf_user_group_relation.user_group_id = xf_user_group.user_group_id
     INNER JOIN xf_user_field_value ON xf_user_group_relation.user_id = xf_user_field_value.user_id
WHERE xf_user_group.display_style_priority >= 500 
      AND field_id = 'minecraft' 
      AND xf_user_group_relation.user_group_id NOT IN(21,22)
GROUP BY xf_user_group_relation.user_id, 
      xf_user_field_value.field_value;
```

The groups are in `xf_user_group` with the structure:

```
user_group_id            int(10)        AUTO_INCREMENT
title                    varchar(50)
display_style_priority   int(10)
user_css                 text
user_title               varchar(100)
```

Comment: Where does the column `field_id` come from? And you want `the group with the highest display priority` overall? Or per user?

Comment: It's per user and field_id comes from xf_user_field_value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql errorneously lets you aggregate values without specifing ALL non-aggregates in GROUP BY. So it chooses on its own what value to show for user_group_id.
To get results you need, one would have to get maximum display_style_priority per user, and then join user_id and value back to original tables to filter them. There are two forms you might use, **join**:

```
SELECT *
FROM xf_user_group_relation
     INNER JOIN xf_user_group 
        ON xf_user_group_relation.user_group_id = xf_user_group.user_group_id
     INNER JOIN xf_user_field_value 
        ON xf_user_group_relation.user_id = xf_user_field_value.user_id
     INNER JOIN
     (
       SELECT r2.user_id, MAX(g2.display_style_priority) display_style_priority
         FROM xf_user_group_relation r2
        INNER JOIN xf_user_group g2 
           ON r2.user_group_id = g2.user_group_id
        GROUP BY r2.user_id
     ) maxDSP
        ON xf_user_group_relation.user_id = maxDSP.user_id
       AND xf_user_group.display_style_priority = maxDSP.display_style_priority
WHERE xf_user_group.display_style_priority >= 500 
      AND field_id = 'minecraft' 
      AND xf_user_group_relation.user_group_id NOT IN(21,22)
```

And **compare to maximum in a subqery:**

```
SELECT *
FROM xf_user_group_relation
     INNER JOIN xf_user_group 
        ON xf_user_group_relation.user_group_id = xf_user_group.user_group_id
     INNER JOIN xf_user_field_value 
        ON xf_user_group_relation.user_id = xf_user_field_value.user_id
WHERE xf_user_group.display_style_priority =
      (SELECT MAX(g2.display_style_priority) 
         FROM xf_user_group_relation r2
        INNER JOIN xf_user_group g2 
           ON r2.user_group_id = g2.user_group_id
        WHERE r2.user_id = xf_user_group_relation.user_id
      )
      AND xf_user_group.display_style_priority >= 500 
      AND field_id = 'minecraft' 
      AND xf_user_group_relation.user_group_id NOT IN(21,22)
```

Live demo is at [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05249/17).

Answer (score 0):

You can add `order by`

```
ORDER BY xf_user_group_relation.user_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this query pairing the group with the lowest ID and saying it has the highest display_style_priorty?

If so a subquery can take care of that for you but I'm not sure what the result you are getting is and what the desired result is

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, this returns the group with the highest display priority per `(user_id, field_value)`, **not** just per user. I assume that is what you want:

```
SELECT r.user_id, 
       x.field_value,
       r.user_group_id, 
       x.max_disp AS display_style_priority
FROM (
    SELECT r.user_id, v.field_value, max(g.display_style_priority) AS max_disp
    FROM   xf_user_group_relation r
    JOIN   xf_user_field_value    v USING (user_id)
    JOIN   xf_user_group          g USING (user_group_id)
    WHERE  g.display_style_priority >= 500 
    AND    v.field_id = 'minecraft' 
    AND    r.user_group_id NOT IN (21,22)
    GROUP  BY r.user_id, v.field_value
    )  x
JOIN  xf_user_group_relation r USING (user_id)
JOIN  xf_user_group g ON g.display_style_priority = x.max_disp
                     AND g.user_group_id = r.user_group_id
```

If a user can have more than one group with the same `display_style_priority`, this can return multiple rows per `(user_id, field_value)` sharing the same maximum display priority.

---

Other RDBMS (like PostgreSQL, MSSQL or Oracle) have **window functions** to radically simplify this kind of task.

In PostgreSQL, your query could work like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       r.user_id
      ,v.field_value
      ,last_value(g.user_group_id) OVER w AS user_group_id
      ,last_value(g.display_style_priority) OVER w AS display_style_priority 
FROM   xf_user_group_relation r
JOIN   xf_user_field_value    v USING (user_id)
JOIN   xf_user_group          g USING (user_group_id)
WHERE  g.display_style_priority >= 500 
AND    v.field_id = 'minecraft' 
AND    r.user_group_id NOT IN (21,22)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY r.user_id, v.field_value
             ORDER BY g.display_style_priority);
```

[Introduction to window functions in the PostgreSQL manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-window.html)